# Why am I getting duplicate query records?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query (`qry_prob`) with the following results:

```
+------+-------------+--------------+
| PK_G | ID1_Prob_Ov | ID1_Prob_Sur |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 1044 | 47.17%      | 72.17%       |
| 1045 | 46.93%      | 53.79%       |
| 1046 | 49.57%      | 50.66%       |
| 1047 | 59.89%      | 66.54%       |
+------+-------------+--------------+
```

From this I want to create another query that takes the 'Prob' fields and creates a blended % for each record using a reference table (`tbl_bldpct`) as follows:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| ID | Bld_Input  | Bld_Pct |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | % Prob Ov  | 15.00%  |
|  2 | % Prob Sur | 85.00%  |
+----+------------+---------+
```

The result should look like this:

```
+------+--------------+
| PK_G | ID1_prob_bld |
+------+--------------+
| 1044 | 68.42%       |
| 1045 | 52.76%       |
| 1046 | 50.50%       |
| 1047 | 65.54%       |
+------+--------------+
```

I've used the following SQL: `SELECT qry_prob.PK_G, [qry_prob].[ID1_Prob_Ov]*(SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID = 1)+[qry_prob].[ID1_Prob_Sur]*(SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID = 2) AS ID1_prob_bld
FROM qry_prob, tbl_bldpct;`

However, I'm getting duplicates rows as follows:

```
+------+--------------+
| PK_G | ID1_prob_bld |
+------+--------------+
| 1044 | 68.42%       |
| 1044 | 68.42%       |
| 1045 | 52.76%       |
| 1045 | 52.76%       |
| 1046 | 50.50%       |
| 1046 | 50.50%       |
| 1047 | 65.54%       |
| 1047 | 65.54%       |
+------+--------------+
```

If I add another row to my reference table I get another row of duplicates so I can see the problem is in the selection of the records from this table but I can't figure out how I fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are doing a `CROSS JOIN` of the 2 tables `qry_prob, tbl_bldpct`. This happens automatically if you just specify the tables separated by comma in the `FROM` clause without mentioning a specific `JOIN` condition:

```
FROM qry_prob, tbl_bldpct
```

As the second table is not needed in your `SELECT`query, you can just safely omit it and get rid of the `CROSS JOIN` (which would return the cartesian product of the 2 table's records).

```
SELECT qry_prob.PK_G, 
   [qry_prob].[ID1_Prob_Ov]*(SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID = 1)
   +[qry_prob].[ID1_Prob_Sur]*(SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID = 2) AS ID1_prob_bld
FROM qry_prob
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with *Distinct*:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    qry_prob.PK_G, 
    [qry_prob].[ID1_Prob_Ov]*(SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID = 1)+[qry_prob].[ID1_Prob_Sur]*(SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID = 2) AS ID1_prob_bld
FROM 
    qry_prob, 
    tbl_bldpct;
```

Or simply remove the table:

```sql
SELECT 
    qry_prob.PK_G, 
        [qry_prob].[ID1_Prob_Ov]*(SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID = 1) +
        [qry_prob].[ID1_Prob_Sur]*(SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID = 2) AS ID1_prob_bld
FROM 
    qry_prob;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join to the `tbl_bldpct` twice.  Unfortunately, MS Access is not very flexible in its `JOIN` syntax, so you need to use cross joins with filtering in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select (qp.ID1_Prob_Ov * bp1.Bld_Pct + qp.ID1_Prob_Sur * bp2.Bld_Pct) as ID1_prob_bld
from qry_prob as qp,
     tbl_bldpct as bp1,
     tbl_bldpct as bp2
where bp1.id = 1 and bp2.id = 2;
```

You can also pre-aggregate `tbl_bldpct`:

```
select (qp.ID1_Prob_oc * bp.Bld_Pct_1 + qp.ID1_Prob * bp.Bld_Pct2) as ID1_prob_bld
from qry_prob as qp, 
     (select max(iif(id = 1, Bld_Pct, null)) as Bld_Pct_1,
             max(iif(id = 1, Bld_Pct, null)) as Bld_Pct_2                 
      from tbl_bldpct
     ) bp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken

```
SELECT Table2.PK_G, [Bld_Input]*0.15+[ Bld_Pct]*0.85 AS ID1_prob_bld
FROM qry_prob;
```

Based on the **Bld_Pct**

```
 SELECT qry_prob.PK_G, qry_prob.Bld_Input* (SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct  WHERE ID =1) + qry_prob.Bld_Pct* (SELECT Bld_Pct FROM tbl_bldpct WHERE ID =2)
FROM qry_prob;
```

Comment: I din't noticed the tbl_bldpct...I revised my answer...is simple